# How to recover data from software RAID 5 disk partition

Tags: linux, software-raid

I have CentOS 5.8 on my computer, with 5x 1TB hard drives.

I used software RAID. (RAID 1 as a boot partition md0, RAID 0 as a root partition md1 and RAID 5 as /home partition md3).

Unfortunately one of these hard drives failed lately and I want to replace it with a new one.

I want to know that is it possible to change this hard drive without data loss?

The important partition is RAID 5 so in theory if one of hard drives failed I should be able to recover its data without any problem. But in practice how can I do that?

Comment: If you've lost a disk in a RAID0 then you've lost the the RAID0 array

Comment: The only Partition that is important for me is /home that is raid 5 on disk 1-5.

Comment: Actually i have a backup of raid 0 partition.

Comment: Unless you lost two drives at the same time, you should never have lost access to your data on the RAID5 volume.

Answer (score 2):

The folks at this location actually mapped the serial numbers of the physical disks to separate names to help identify those in the RAID array.  They used UDEV rules for it.  This eliminates the guesswork since serial numbers are typically written on the disk paper labels.

In the below link you'll find real 2 drive failure on a RAID6 setup (+) and recovery.  Take a look.  You might be able to identify in a similar way which drive you need to unplug.

Regards,

[RAID 6 + XFS + MDADM](http://www.microdevsys.com/WordPress/2012/04/02/linux-htpc-home-backup-mdadm-raid6-lvm-xfs-cifs-and-nfs/3/)

[RAID 6 UDEV Naming](http://www.microdevsys.com/WordPress/2012/04/01/linux-persistent-naming-of-sata-devices-through-udev-rules/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
mdadm --add /dev/md3 /dev/<disk>
```

… where `<disk>` is of the form `sda1`, `sdb1`, `sdc1`, etc.

Comment: Is this command recover my data too?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you disk setup is as follows:
[image: Disk layout constructed from the comments]

With:
sda1 and sdb1 as md1 (mirrored)  root
sda2 and sdb2 as md0 (striped)   boot
sda3, sdb3, sdc1, sdd1 and sde1 as md2 (RAID5) /home

Since you lost drive 2 (sdb) you:

- You lost md0. A stripe needs **all* of its drives. You will need to restore this from backup or reinstall it.
- You lost one drive from md1. Since that is a mirror it will still work.  (without redundancy atm)
- You lost on drive from md2. Since that is a RAID5 is will work with one drive lost. You should still be able to access all your data.

My first step would be to check my backups. Nothing should go wrong while you fix your RAID arrays. But it is better to be safe and have backups. Since both / and /home are still readable in degraded mode I suggest to start with that.

Afterward pull the broken drive (disk 2, aka sdb), replace it with a new drive and partition the drive. I understood from your comments that it used the same setup as the first drive. Which means that you can configure it correctly from your notes, or 'spy' at sda.

Next fix the three broken RAID arrays.

md0 is lost. You will need to recreate it and restore from backup.

md1 might work with `mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`

md2 might work with `mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1`

**Might**. I am a BSD guy (not a Linux user) which uses hardware RAID cards. Please double check everything before committing to these commands. This includes your checking your backups.

Comment: The problem is i used some part of each drive for specific drive, i mean for example i add 100G of sda and sdb as root partition, 200M of sda and sdb for root partition and remaining space of sda and sdb and also the whole sdc sdd and sde as a /home partition!

Comment: the failed disk is sdb, so should i first create sdb2 partition? how can i do that?

Comment: sda1 and sdb1 as root partition (md1)
sda2 and sdb2 as boot partition (md2)

Comment: I make a backup from are available data, now the problem is i dont know how can i partition this new disk in a way that is usable by software raid. how can i do that? these new partitions should be in what format?

Comment: I did that but i got "no devices found for md0"

Comment: "mdadm --assemble -scan" didnt work for me too, same error appeared.

Comment: I find out that this error is because of old version of my rescue disk so i tried centOS 6 rescue mode, no new error is shown:
"/dev/sdb1 has no superblock-- assembly aborted."
FYI /dev/sdb1 is a new partition that i created on new hard drive with same cylinder size as /dev/sda1 partition.

Comment: fdisk -l shows that all the old partitions are labeled as "linux raid autodetect" but the new partitions (/dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2) labeled as "linux" and "extended"!

Comment: i changed new partition type to "linux raid autodetect" but same error still exist:
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has no superblock-- assembly aborted!

Comment: For md0 that might be because you lost the entire RAID and there is nothing to restore. Recreate it with `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2`. Before you do that consider if you really want this to be a stripe again or if a mirror is better. After all, how often are you **writing** to /boot. And Reading should be just as fast with mirror (for which you replace the `--level=0` with `--level=1`).

Comment: No actually same error appeared for md3 too.
there is a raid 1 partition called md0 and a raid 5 partition called md3 that should recover. In each two cases the superblock error exists.

Comment: could you add your mdadm.conf, and the output of mdadm -examine?

Comment: Where the mdadm.conf is located?

Comment: It is located in /etc/

Comment: mdadm --examine said: no devices to examine

Comment: i tried "mdadm --assemble --scan -v" it could not assemble md0 and md3! Now it seems that this command made some unwanted changes! now the system did not even recognize md0, md1, md2 and md3!!! it give me "/dev/md1" no such file or directory! it seems that this command change /dev/md1 to /dev/md/1_0 and also other partitions too!

Comment: now i tried mdadm --examine -scan, here is the output:
ARRAY: /dev/md125 UUID [some character]
ARRAY: /dev/md2   UUID [some character]
ARRAY: /dev/md1   UUID [some character]
ARRAY: /dev/md3   UUID [some character]
what happened to md0?!!! it changes to md125 now!!!

Comment: Is the any way that i can recover my drives in this way? i saw some posts that says create a new array and try to resync raid drives, would this help? how can i change md125 to md0?

Comment: Before you will this entire space with comments: Please use the [Edit] function to add information to your post. E.g. post your mdadm.conf (as asked 20h ago **before** it potentially got changed by recovery options). If an improved post does not get an answer try giving it a bounty. (Fo-r that you need reputation, which is gained by successfully answering other peoples questions).

Comment: edit option just give you 5 min to change something so this made me to add new comment.

Comment: That is edit on a **comment**. Edit the **post**.